# How to deal with error applying BeanValidation relational constraints?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, constraints

I've got some problems with making oneToMany relation in Spring + Hibernate 4.1 application
This is my entities classes. Every USER_ROLE record has FK to USER record. I can't find anything useful on the Internet.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "USERS" )
public class User {

     long id;
     String login;
     String password;
     String name;
     String surname;
     GregorianCalendar birthDate;
     String email;
     GregorianCalendar joinDate;
     String randomKey;
     List<UserRole> userRoles = new ArrayList<UserRole>();

    public User(){ } //JavaBean Hibernate requirement

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name="USER_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setAccountRole(List<UserRole> aUserRoles) {
        for (UserRole role : aUserRoles) {
            this.addUserRole(role);
        }
    }

    public void addUserRole(UserRole aRole) {
        if (!this.userRoles.contains(aRole)) {
            aRole.setUser(this);
            this.userRoles.add(aRole);
        }
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLE")
public class UserRole {

    Integer roleId;
    String role;
    User user;

    public UserRole() { }

//  public UserRole(String role) {
//      this.setRole(role);
//  }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(Integer roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    @Basic
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User aUser) {
        this.user = aUser;
    }
}
```

And this is first exception in my stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: pl.rafalo235.encyklopedia.model.dao.UserDAO pl.rafalo235.encyklopedia.controllers.HomeController.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean pl.rafalo235.encyklopedia.model.dao.UserDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/encyklopediaDispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4935)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the default constructor, that's not a requirement.

Comment: When do you get this exception? At startup? When you're trying to persist?

Answer (score 15):

I'm not using Spring and I'm using hibernate 4.1.8 and works adding to my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
```

Answer (score 12):

Try add to hibernate config in Spring **validation.mode** - none:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            ....
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using JPA and Hibernate works for me adding to persistence.xml:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none"/>
```